# Which is the best way to catch exceptions with Spark Streaming and Cassandra Connector?

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm running a Spark Streaming job with Spark version 1.4.1, Cassandra and Kafka.

The Job read events from a Kafka topic elaborate it and store to Cassandra table.

My Sample Job Class:

```
    import com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil;
    import com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraStreamingJavaUtil;
    import com.finscience.messages.StatusMessageHandler;
    import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
    import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder;
    import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
    import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
    import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel;
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairDStream;
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairInputDStream;
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils;
    import scala.Tuple2;

    import java.util.*;

    public class CassandraTest {


        StatusMessageHandler statusMessageHandler;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();

            sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1");
            sparkConf.setAppName("test");
            sparkConf.setMaster("local[*]");

            JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.milliseconds(1000));


            Map<String, Integer> kafkaTopics = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            kafkaTopics.put("topic_test", 1);

            Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

            kafkaParams.put("zookeeper.connect", "127.0.0.1:2181");
            kafkaParams.put("group.id", "consumer_group_test");

            Integer kafkaSparkReceivers = 1;

            StorageLevel messagesStorageLevel = StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY();

            //create a list of receiver
            List<JavaPairDStream<String, String>> kafkaStreams = new ArrayList<>(kafkaSparkReceivers);
            for (int i = 0; i < kafkaSparkReceivers; i++) {
                // Create kafka stream with brokers and topics
                JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> messagesStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, String.class, String.class,
                        StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, kafkaParams, kafkaTopics, messagesStorageLevel);
                kafkaStreams.add(messagesStream);
            }


            JavaPairDStream<String, String> unifiedKafkaStream = kafkaStreams.get(0);

            //there is only one receiver
            if (kafkaSparkReceivers > 1) {
                //unify stream of different receiver
                unifiedKafkaStream = ssc.union(kafkaStreams.get(0), kafkaStreams.subList(1, kafkaStreams.size()));
            }


            JavaDStream<TestTable> contentPayloadElementsStream = unifiedKafkaStream.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, TestTable>() {
                @Override
                public TestTable call(Tuple2<String, String> stringStringTuple2) throws Exception {
                    return new TestTable(new JsonParser().parse(stringStringTuple2._2()).getAsJsonObject().get("uuid").getAsString());
                }
            });


        CassandraStreamingJavaUtil.javaFunctions(contentPayloadElementsStream).writerBuilder("test", "table1", CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow(TestTable.class)).saveToCassandra();

        ssc.start();
        ssc.awaitTermination();


    }


    static public class TestTable {

        private UUID id;

        public TestTable(String id) {
            this.id = UUID.fromString(id);

        }

        public UUID getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(UUID id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

}
```

When Cassandra is busy or unreachable I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 20.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 20.0 (TID 37, localhost): java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {127.0.0.1}:9042
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:164)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:150)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:150)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:31)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:56)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:81)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:109)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.write(TableWriter.scala:139)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.streaming.DStreamFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DStreamFunctions.scala:34)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.streaming.DStreamFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DStreamFunctions.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9042] Channel has been closed))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:223)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:78)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1272)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.getMetadata(Cluster.java:336)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:157)
    ... 15 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1273)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1264)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1263)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1263)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1457)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

I need to notify this problem to email. Which the best way is to catch the above exception?

Comment: Hi, were you able to find the fix for this? Even I have to do the exact solution now.